# How to create User Profile in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

Hi i am developing one social community app.In this app one functionality is there.The Functionality is Creating the user profile(username,address,MobileNo,Email).Those are all added in the user profile like facebook app.I am using webservices json parser using jsp webserver. I have no idea how to create user profile like facebook type.Please give me any idea.Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you done any R & D ?

Comment: Ya i done some R&D.But i cant get any idea.

Comment: also i want to upload images like facebook profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

You can do research on it. As there are many fields, you can use in user profile. You can check application from app store or somewhere else. And then you have to do as per your requirement.